# How to send collection as an excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel 3.1 from https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/ and I am trying to figure out if there is a simple way to simply render a collection as an excel file.

In my controller, I have code that generates a db query and puts it into a view. I'd like to give the user the ability to download the data in that view as an excel document. The code used to create the view is not simple, and it is based on many query inputs.

In my `PatientsController.php`, I have

```
public function excelExport(Request $request)
{
    $params = $this->getQueryParams($request);
    $pts = $this->createIndexCollection($request, $params);

    return Excel::download(new PatientsExport, 'patients.xlsx');
}
```

I'd like to pass the already-computed collection `$pts` to the download command. Is this possible?

`PatientsExport` is copied straight from the docs.

Comment: could you please show `getQueryParams` and `createIndexCollection` content

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example from official documentation:

https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/collection.html

```
class PatientsExport implements FromCollection
{
    private $your_collection;

    public function __construct($pts) {
        $this->your_collection = $pts;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->your_collection;
    }

}
```

and then try:

```
public function excelExport(Request $request) { 
{
    $params = $this->getQueryParams($request);
    $pts = $this->createIndexCollection($request, $params);
    return Excel::download(new PatientExport($pts), 'invoices.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: why someone set -1? :)) explain pls

Comment: I haven't tested it, but the class `PatientsExport` is not the same class as `PatientsController`, so using `$this->` won't work. Is there a way to send the premade collection or the controller as a dependency injection?

Comment: What do you mean it won't work. It will work. I understand that those are different classes. PatientExport is implementing FromCollection interface. And when you put PatientExport instance to download method it will automatically call collection method..

Comment: oh you mean `getQueryParams` method, yes, I mentioned in my answer, that you should move those 2 methods to that class if this is possible.

Comment: I have edited answer if you dont want or cant move collection functionality to PatientExport class... please have a look

Answer (score -1):

you have to make a class to export the collection to achive this make a file in app/Export patientsexport.php and add this content

```
namespace App\Export;

use App\PatientsExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class PatientsExports implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return PatientsExport::all();
    }
}
```

now you can access in your  controller

```
use App\PatientsExport\PatientsExports;
public function excelExport(Request $request)
{
    $params = $this->getQueryParams($request);
    $pts = $this->createIndexCollection($request, $params);
    return Excel::download(new PatientsExports, 'patients.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: why did you write this one `return Invoice::all();`? How I see, you just copied from docs that example

Comment: where do you use $pts? :( and I am not sure that PatientsExports is eloquent and has `all()` method

Comment: `$pts` is set in the `createIndexCollection()` command. It returns a collection which  is used for a view. I'd like to use the same collection as a downloadable excel sheet.